# RXTXCommDriver problem

Tags: java, exception, classloader, rxtx

Hi i have simple code:

```
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        Enumeration pList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        while (pList.hasMoreElements()) {
          CommPortIdentifier cpi = (CommPortIdentifier) pList.nextElement();
          System.out.print("Port " + cpi.getName() + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

I have install library as they wrote [here](http://www.agaveblue.org/howtos/Comm_How-To.shtml)

and i get such error

`java.lang.ClassCastException: gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver cannot be cast to gnu.io.CommDriver thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver`

whats wrong ?? Im working on ubuntu.

Comment: Could you post the whole exception please (especially line numbers)?